# Как работать с фоновой передачей данных в AJAX и сервлетами

Tags: ajax, servlet

Как работать с фоновой передачей данных в AJAX и сервлетами?Точнее ,как передать данные обратно из  сервлета в клиент , который отправил запрос через AJAX  фоновой передачей данных?
Вот запрос с клиента.

```js
            $.ajax(
                {
                type:'post',
                url:'controller',
                data:{'x55': x, 'y': y, 'r': R,'Flag':false},
                response:'text', 
                success:function (data)
                {//возвращаый результат от сервера
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

Вот моя попытка ответа из сервлета.Но в результате клиент получает только "??????????????????".

```js
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String xString=request.getParameter("InputX");
        String yString=request.getParameter("InputY");
        String RString=request.getParameter("InputR");
        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter writer=response.getWriter();
        writer.print("1234567890");
        }
```

Как это исправить